# How to deploy custom fields across orgs using Mavensmate?

Tags: custom-field, sandbox, mavensmate, import

I have 2 Salesforce orgs (both sandboxes): I want to move the custom fields I've added from the first Org (Origin) to the 2nd (Target). I've downloaded the most recent beta version of Mavensmate and have successfully created a Sublime Text project with the object xml containing the custom fields.

I've tried 3 different approaches to update the custom fields on the Target org, none of which have worked so far:

1, created a separate Mavensmate project and copied the `package.xml` and `src` directories from the Origin project, but the separate Mavensmate project doesn't recognize the updated files (even after a Refresh Metadata).

2, created a deployment connection from the original Mavensmate project to the Target Salesforce org. I can see the custom fields in the Deployment Metadata, and the deployment says that it is successful, but the custom fields are not pushed to the Salesforce org.

3, tried an older version of Mavensmate but can't log into the sandbox even after resetting the Security Token per the instructions.

Anyone have any advice? it seems like #2 should work...

Comment: How you are verifying that custom fields not updated from #2?

Comment: Hi Pragati - I'm logging into the target org separately (outside of Mavesmate) to verify the deployed fields.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the custom metadata migration successfully using the [Salesforce Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/) with Java 1.8 & Ant 1.10.1